# Laravel 8x create user table with JetStream Teams

Tags: laravel

I am building a web app and running Laravel teams, I have made a user table but am unsure how to nest the data so that the users are viewing their main team. From my research I have found:

```
return App\Models\Calendar::where(
    'team_id', $request->user()->currentTeam->id
)->get();
```

or

```
// Access a user's "personal" team...
$user->personalTeam() : Laravel\Jetstream\Team
```

but I need a little help applying it properly as I've never done it.

My current view, Controller, and route are:

View is just a standard table which I built to show with a foreach method:

```
<div class="">
{{$user->name}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function render()
    {
        # Load all users and sort by name    
        return view('users.table',[
            'users' => User::orderBy('name')->paginate($this->perPage)
        ]);
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group( function () {
Route::resource('users', \App\Http\Livewire\Users::class);
});
```

I tried to cut down the code so it's easier to give me suggestions, let me know if I missed anything.

This is my current screenshot of the users table:

[image]

File tree

[image]

Comment: What is exactly you try to achieve?

Comment: @tirtakeniten I am wanting to have a table with the teams' users that a user can view when logged in. I have got it so I can show all users but don't know how to make it only show the current team

Comment: @tirtakeniten I am wanting to have a table with the teams' users that a user can view when logged in. I have got it so I can show all users but don't know how to make it only show the current team

Comment: Are you using laravel jetstream?

Comment: Yes I am, with laravel 8x

Comment: @tirtakeniten So currently what I have is the user clicks on the Users tab and they see the whole system of users but I want them to only see their current teams one. The idea is I am using the team system as branches for the business

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
User::orderBy('name')->paginate($this->perPage)
```

with

```
Team::find(Auth::user()->current_team_id)->users()->paginate($this->perPage)
```

Comment: This is what I thought would be the case but gives me error: 
Class 'App\Http\Livewire\Users\Team' not found (\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)

I added my file tree to show you, do I need to adjust my route?

Comment: You must include use statement at the top the page for your Team class, probably like use App\Team

Comment: I Can't seem to get it to go, I even tried use `Laravel\Jetstream\Team as JetstreamTeam;`